# ASP.NET url routing, default path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-routing

I expected this would also map the default homepage as in http://localhost/ but it is not hit.

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route("{Keyword}", new HomeHandler()));
```

Question is of course why not? I would like to map the root to some other page.

Comment: Could you show your complete routing table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this yet but try removing the default document from IIS's configuration. For IIS 7 this setting is in `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument>
   <files>
    <clear />
   </files>
  </defaultDocument>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is somewhat complex. It was on IIS6 and we had to add a specific property. I cannot really remember what we did back then but you can google it, that's how I found it.

Comment: It would be more useful to put in a link to what you found.